# Magento 2.3: How to filter product collection by stock status

Tags: php, magento2.3, product-collection

Having trouble figuring out how to filter a product collection by in stock / out of stock status. My goal is to get all out of stock products that also match some other filters:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
  ) {
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
  }

$product = $this->collectionFactory->create()
      ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
      ->addFieldToFilter('quantity_and_stock_status', array('eq' => 0))
      ->addFieldToFilter('supply_discontinued', array('eq' => 1))
      ->addFieldToFilter('status', 1)
      ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(3,4)))
      ->setPageSize(1)
      ->getFirstItem();
```

Filtering by `quantity_and_stock_status` doesn't seem to work in this instance. Is there another way to filter by stock status as well as the other filters I have listed?

Answer (score 1):

please find a small snippet that may pinpoint where in the Magento core code you can look for code reference

```
/** @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status */
    private $stockStatus;

    /**
     * @param $website
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    private function getWebsiteProductInStockCollection($website): \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addWebsiteFilter($website->getId());
        $this->stockStatus->addIsInStockFilterToCollection($collection);

        return $collection;
    }
```